# Debian: Plymouth configuration with installed video card

Tags: linux, splash-screen, boot, video-card

I'm running Debian 6.0.7 Squeeze and installed Plymouth to get a splash screen to cover up the system calls that appear on boot. I also have an nVidia graphics card installed for which I have already installed drivers for and followed the debian plymouth guide from [here](https://wiki.debian.org/plymouth). Instead of seeing the THEME that I set, i get a blue and white progress bar to appear at the bottom of the screen. What am I missing to be able to see the set THEMES at boot via the new graphics card.???

Comment: legacy system, have to use squeeze :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected and happens because NVIDIA proprietary driver does not support kernel modesetting, so a graphical animation cannot be displayed at boot. Instead, Plymouth falls back to the default textual theme.

Comment: do you know if there is a work around for this? I assume that having a   different video card that supports modesetting would also resolve the issue, correct?

Comment: 1. Unfortunately, no. No workaround in your situation AFAIK, _unless you could use the open source driver_, but Squeeze's version might be too old. Have a look if there is a recent kernel in backports, but I assume you won't change a critical part of the system only because of an animation at boot :) 2. Yes, Intel videocards support modesetting and will display  graphic animation at boot.

Comment: thanks for update. I'm not tied to Plymouth, is there an alternative technology available for splash screens?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Kernel modesetting is necessary for displaying a graphical animation at boot.

Comment: When looking for a new video card, what indicates if it supports modesetting?

Comment: It depends on the driver, not on the videocard. NVIDIA and ATi proprietary driver do not support modesetting, all the open source drivers (including the official ones for Intel videocards) do.